# Standard utility to write stdin to a file with no stdout?

Tags: linux, shell

I have two cases where I want to create a file with its contents supplied on standard input:

1. I need to use `sudo` to have the privileges to create a file.
2. An application always invokes an (interactive) editor specified by `$EDITOR` to process this input further, but I want to pipe data from a program instead.

In the former case, I could use `echo test | sudo bash -c 'cat > test.txt'`, but in this as well as in the latter case I usually use `tee` and direct `tee`'s standard output to `/dev/null`:

1. `echo test | sudo tee test.txt > /dev/null`
2. `echo test | EDITOR=tee application > /dev/null`

However, this does not only throw away `tee`'s standard output, but also (in the latter case) `application`'s.  It would be preferable to be able to specifically suppress `tee`'s standard output, so that I could instantly notice if something else wrote to standard output.

Is there a utility on standard Linux distributions that will write standard input to the file specified as a command line argument and not output anything?

Comment: This question sounds like an "XY Problem". What are you really trying to do?

Comment: No, this is typical when using sudo to write a file : you want the write handled by sudo, hence the shell redirection is not usable here. Legit question, and legit answer, as `sed` is definitely a standard utility.

Answer (score 6):

There's the `w` command of `sed`:

```
sed -n 'w /tmp/out'
```

But perhaps you should just write your own script `mycat`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat >"${1?}"
```

Create a directory ~/bin and add it to the front of your PATH so your command is found.

You may say, "but I use hundreds of machines, they won't have this script on them". In that case my suggestion is that you create a script that simply sets up your preferred environment on any machine you want. I have a script that will, ideally when I have root access, create a new user id, add a sudoers entry for it, copy some .bashrc and bin/* files, and so on. Then I can login under that id and "feel at home".  Also, my command history is then not polluted by other admins doing root logins, and I am not doing all my commands as root.

I often have to work on brand new OS installations on hardware under test, and this sort of automatic setup is a real blessing.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not address my question.  I'm looking for a standard utility that takes one argument and writes stdin to it.  I know how to write wrapper scripts, deploy software, etc.; avoiding that effort is the point of this question.

Comment: I though `sed -n 'w /tmp/out'` was pretty cool.